# Sales pipeline chart

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I'm trying to create a sales pipeline chart using d3. Below is an example. Does anyone know of any example code I can start with?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/FKoHk.png]

Appreciate any help.

Comment: I found a highcharts solution.
http://jsfiddle.net/JvY4s/815/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a project on github called [funnel-plots](https://github.com/annapowellsmith/funnel-plots) by [Anna Powell-Smith](http://anna.ps/) that could give you a head start.  You are going to need to establish some definitions upfront to render this.  There are some who feel that this graph is [kind of meaningless](http://blog.spark59.com/2012/why-not-the-funnel-chart/) (I happen to feel that there are better graphs), but they are something that people expect to see, so here is how you can address them.  First you need to decide if the steps have uniform height and their widths are variable (so at each step you are decreasing the width by the same percent that the plotted value is decreasing) or if the min and max values are determined by their plotted value but the height of steps in between are adjusted to represent their plotted value (using the volume of each step) which is the approach of the referenced chart in your question.

Comment: Thanks Jason. I'm looking a bit more help - for example, sample jsfiddle code.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the article on funnel charts. Nice read.

Answer (score 3):

For a different approach, here is an example using entirely CSS:

```
<div id='chart'>
  <div id='plotA'>&nbsp;</div>
  <div id='plotB'>&nbsp;</div>
  <div id='plotC'>&nbsp;</div>
  <div id='plotD'>&nbsp;</div>
  <div id='plotE'>&nbsp;</div>
</div>

#chart {
  text-align: center;
}
#chart div {
  margin-top: 2px;
}
#plotA {
  border-top: 5px solid #3B5592;
  border-left: 2px solid transparent;
  border-right: 2px solid transparent;
  height: 0; width: 200px;
}
#plotB {
  border-top: 100px solid #BF2E2B;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  height: 0; width: 100px;
}
#plotC {
  margin-left: 50px;
  border-top: 50px solid #8CB638;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 25px solid transparent;
  height: 0; width: 50px;
}
#plotD {
  margin-left: 74px;
  border-top: 23px solid #684A94;
  border-left: 16px solid transparent;
  border-right: 16px solid transparent;
  height: 0; width: 18px;
}
#plotE {
  margin-left: 90px;
  border-top: 15px solid #24A4C7;
  border-left: 7px solid transparent;
  border-right: 7px solid transparent;
  height: 0; width: 4px;
}
```

[with a demo](http://cssdesk.com/F24NK)

Comment: Clever use of CSS. Thanks Jason. Still looking for a D3 solution :)